# c# play stop a wav file

Tags: c#

I have a button that has the ability to play and stop a waf file. 
In the handler button method i have

```
if (button.Text="play")
{
..filepath of the wav file
wav.play();
button.txt="stop"
}
else{
wav.stop();      
button.Text="play"
}
```

but when the debugger goes on the else the wav is null , so i have a null exception.where am i wrong?

Comment: What is `wav`? Where is it defined and initialized? Post more code please.

Comment: Can you privide full code of buttin click handler?

Comment: Add the code that you initialize the wav object. Beside this, check if the wav object is not null before you call the play()

Answer (score 1):

You, have given the `wavv` instead of `wav` in the else case, so it might be making it null.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing,

```
    if (button.txt="play") 
    { //..filepath of the wav file 
      if(wav != null)
      {        
        wav.play(); 
        button.txt="stop";
      }
    } 
    else
    { 
      if(wav != null)
      {  
    wav.stop(); //replaced wavv to wav 
    button.txt="play"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code it is look like that you are declare and initialize wav in if part, 
so it will not be available in the else part. You should declare wav outside the if...else
and then use wav.stop();

```
    //declare wav variable here
    if (button.Text="play")
    {
      if(wav != null)
      {        
       //filepath of the wav file
        wav.play(); 
        button.txt="stop";
      }
    }
    else{
        if(wav != null)
      {
        wav.stop(); 
        button.txt="play";
      }
    }
```

I think this will help you...